# Printing string in JavaScript is giving error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print 2 strings. What is wrong here?

```js
function alpha(name1, name2){
  console.log(name1, name2);
}
```

```html
<button onclick=alpha("Peter", "Jack")>ok</button>
```

Comment: You need to quote the attribute with other quotes than the ones in the call. For example `onclick='alpha("Peter", "Jack")'` I would prefer the other way around: `onclick="alpha('Peter', 'Jack')"`

Comment: Thanks guys, I just don't like someone downvoting .... without telling answer! BTW ... thanks to all who helped out!

Comment: It's likely downvoted because it is really a typo-type question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrongly defining the handler of `onclick`.

```js
function alpha(name1, name2){
  console.log(name1, name2);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alpha('Peter', 'Jack')">ok</button>
```

Comment: really worth an answer and not a typo-type vote?

Comment: Dude ... it was not a typo! I seriously, missed that point.

Comment: "Typo type" as in Fixed by adding two characters

Answer (score 2):

Others have already told you that the issue is that the value of your `onclick` needs to be quoted and those quotes should not conflict with the quotes you are already using around your function arguments, but I have a different approach for you....

You really shouldn't be using inline HTML event attributes (i.e. `onclick`) in the first place. This is a 25+ year old technique that just won't die because it's easy to understand and most new developers just copy someone else's code and convert it to their needs. [There are many reasons why this old technique should just fade away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) and instead, you should use the modern API for event binding, which is [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

In your case, it's not obvious why a `button` would have function arguments hard-coded into it, but if that really is your use case, those should be stored as [data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Here's your scenario, reworked into code from this century:

```js
// Get a reference to the DOM element you need to work with
let btn = document.querySelector("button");

// Get the data-* into an array
let people = btn.dataset.people.split(",");

// Do the event binding in JavaScript, not HTML
// We'll set the click event to invoke an anonymous
// function that itself calls the real function and
// passes the proper arguments.
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  alpha(people[0], people[1]);
});

function alpha(name1, name2){
  console.log(name1, name2);
}
```

```html
<!-- Notice that the data is held in a data-* attribute and 
     that the code to hook up the event is gone from the HTML. -->
<button data-people="Peter,Jack">ok</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a pair of quotes.

```html
<button onclick="alpha('Peter', 'Jack')">ok</button>
```

Comment: A pair of *parentheses*? Your answer did not add any parentheses.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the comments to the question before answering as well as the other answers and their comments

Comment: My mistake, thank you for correcting, I did mean quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You need quotation marks around the function in HTML

```js
function alpha(name1, name2){
  console.log(name1, name2);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alpha('Peter', 'Jack')">ok</button>
```

Comment: Please read the comments to the question before answering as well as the other answers and their comments

Comment: @mplungjan there were no comments when i was typing :)

Comment: I commented 2 minutes after the question was asked and 4 minutes before your post - anyway, it is not worth answering

Answer (score -2):

Using Single quotes '' in the html instead of double will solve the issue. Also put quotes around the function

```js
function alpha(name1, name2){
  console.log(name1, name2);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alpha('Peter', 'Jack')">ok</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the comments to the question before answering as well as the other answers and their comments